# For a real number x > 0 , consider the interval I n = (− x n, x n), where n ≥1 is an integer number. Calculate x such that:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a real number $x > 0$ , consider the interval $I_n = (− x^n, x^n)$, where $n\geq 1$ is an integer
number. Calculate $x$ such that: $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\subseteq [-2,1)$.

Comment: Clearly any $x\in (0,1)$ works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x \in (0,1)$. Then $x^{n+1} < x^n \; \forall n$, so $I_{n+1} \subset I_n \; \forall n$ and hence $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = I_1 = (-x, x) \subset [-2,1)$